# Camera not working on Raspberry Pi 3B Running Debian Bullseye

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

Pi Model: Raspberry Pi 3B
OS: Debian version: 11 (bullseye)
Camera: Arducam Lens Board OV5647

I have connected my Raspberry Pi to my camera module and attempted to check its functionality with libcamera-hello and received many errors and don't understand and don't know how to fix:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-hello
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:12:08.939523509] [3687]
INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp: 293 libcamera vO.0.0
+3548-a11d63f9
[0:12:08.989428234] [3701] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor. pp: 591
lov5647 10-
0036: Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[0:12:09.052549739] [3701]
INFO PI raspberrypi.cpp:1352 Registered camera /ba
se/soc/12c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev
/media©
I
[0:12:09.054217200] [3687]
INFO Camera camera.pp: 1029 configuring streams:
1296x972-YUV420
[0:12:09.054873623] [3701]
INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp: 760 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0
mux/i2c@1/ov5647036
Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected
unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
[0:12:09.174547538] [3705]
INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp: 635 Request ctrl: Satur
lation
= 1.000000
[0:12:09.174754350] [3705]
INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp: 635 Request ctrl: Contr
last = 1.000000
[0:12:09.174811586] [3705]
Itness
= 0.000000
INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.pp:635 Request ctrl: Brigh
[0:12:09.174868198] [3705]
Ide
= O
INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.pp: 635 Request ctrl: AwbMo
[0:12:09.174921841] [3705]
INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.pp: 635 Request ctrl: Sharp
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

On Raspberry Pi 3 and earlier devices running Bullseye you need to re-enable Glamor in order to make the X-Windows hardware accelerated preview window work. To do this enter sudo raspi-config at a terminal window and then choose Advanced Options, Glamor and Yes. Finally quit raspi-config and let it reboot your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same output on a 3B running Bullseye 64-bit, and the camera works fine.

The `ERROR` at the top about "Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes" is not fatal.  The rest of that output is just `INFO`; **there are no further problems** indicated.

Exactly what `libcamera-hello` is supposed to do beyond that I'm not sure, perhaps if run in a GUI environment it uses the preview window or something.

Try:

```
libcamera-jpeg -o test.jpg
```

This will leave a `test.jpg` in the current directory, and output as follows:

```
Preview window unavailable
[0:04:36.088484891] [1007]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3548-a11d63f9
[0:04:36.142284474] [1008] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:591 'ov5647 10-0036': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[0:04:36.180085159] [1008]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1352 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:04:36.181508458] [1007]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1029 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[0:04:36.182155289] [1008]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:760 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
[0:04:36.216808799] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[0:04:36.216960936] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[0:04:36.217015468] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[0:04:36.217064375] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[0:04:36.217111979] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[0:04:36.217161355] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[0:04:36.217232293] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[0:04:36.217278127] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 33333, 33333 ]
[0:04:36.217330420] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[0:04:36.217376827] [1012]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 3
[0:04:41.353418179] [1007]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1029 configuring streams: (0) 2592x1944-YUV420 (1) 2592x1944-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[0:04:41.355231899] [1008]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:760 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 2592x1944-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 2592x1944-pGAA
[0:04:41.450735791] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Saturation = 1.000000
[0:04:41.450897095] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Contrast = 1.000000
[0:04:41.450952981] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Brightness = 0.000000
[0:04:41.451001732] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AwbMode = 0
[0:04:41.451540072] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: Sharpness = 1.000000
[0:04:41.451605646] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: ExposureValue = 0.000000
[0:04:41.451886847] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AeExposureMode = 0
[0:04:41.451937056] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: FrameDurationLimits = [ 100, 1000000000 ]
[0:04:41.452359092] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: AeMeteringMode = 0
[0:04:41.452413260] [1015]  INFO IPARPI raspberrypi.cpp:635 Request ctrl: NoiseReductionMode = 2
Still capture image received
```